# Unable to fetch in redux dispatch function

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

First, I'm still new to the React/Redux world.

I have the following action in my actions/index.js

```
export function fetchLatestSchedule()
{
    //const uri = '/rest/schedule';
    console.log("Fetching latest schedule action");
    const uri = 'http://localhost:8585/MissionClockService/rest/schedule';
    return dispatch => {
        console.log("Fetching latest schedule action function");
        return fetch(uri)
        .then(response => {
            console.log("response: " + response);
            return response.json().then(body => ({ response, body }));}
        )
        .then(({ response, body }) => {
            console.log("Response from schedule fetch: " + body);
          if (!response.ok) {
            dispatch({
              type: SCHEDULE_REQUEST_FAILURE,
              payload: body.error
            });
          } else {
            dispatch({
              type: SET_CONTACTS,
              payload: body
            });
          }
        });
    }

}
```

My store is created in a store/index.js

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reducers from '../reducers/index';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default store;
```

And finally my component that uses the action is the following (MissionClockApp.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NextContactPanel from './NextContactPanel';
import CurrentContactPanel from './CurrentContactPanel';
import ConfigMenu from './components/ConfigMenu';
import FileModal from './components/FileModal';
import WebsocketConnection from './components/WebsocketConnection';
import {fetchDefaultConfig, fetchLatestSchedule} from './actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const mapDispatchToProp = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchData: function(){
            console.log("Fetching data");
            dispatch(fetchDefaultConfig);
            dispatch(fetchLatestSchedule);
        }
    };
  }

class ConnectedMissionClockApp extends React.Component
{
    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.props.fetchData();
    }

    render()
    {
        return (<div>
            <ConfigMenu/>
            <NextContactPanel/>
            <CurrentContactPanel/>
            <FileModal/>
            <WebsocketConnection/>
        </div>);
    }
}

const MissionClockApp = connect(null, mapDispatchToProp)(ConnectedMissionClockApp);
export default MissionClockApp
```

When I look in the browser debug log, I see my messages up to "Fetching latest schedule action" but then nothing after that, and my REST service isn't getting any sort of request in the GET method.

I'm sure it's something really basic I'm missing but when looking at examples like on https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions or other SO posts, I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.  Other than a dispatch(...) call where my console.log and uri set is happening (which I don't care about dispatching a "making a request" state change), my code seems pretty much identical to the examples.

Where did I screw up here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not actually dispatching the thunks correctly.

Let me paste in an example from [a gist I wrote demonstrating various forms of dispatching](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/6c7608eee5d2421966d3df5edbb8f05c):

```
// approach 1: dispatching a thunk function
const innerThunkFunction1 = (dispatch, getState) => {
    // do useful stuff with dispatch and getState        
};
this.props.dispatch(innerThunkFunction1);

// approach 2: use a thunk action creator to define the function        
const innerThunkFunction = someThunkActionCreator(a, b, c);
this.props.dispatch(innerThunkFunction);

// approach 3: dispatch thunk directly without temp variable        
this.props.dispatch(someThunkActionCreator(a, b, c));

// approach 4: pre-bind thunk action creator to automatically call dispatch
const boundSomeThunkActionCreator = bindActionCreators(someThunkActionCreator, dispatch);
boundSomeThunkActionCreator(a, b, c);
```

The function that takes `(dispatch, getState) => {}` is the actual thunk function.  The outer function is a "thunk action creator", that returns the thunk function.

When you write `dispatch(fetchDefaultConfig);`, you are passing the *thunk action creator* to `dispatch`, but not the *actual thunk function* itself.

When the thunk middleware sees a function come through the pipeline, it runs that function.  So, it's trying to run your action creator, and pass in `(dispatch, getState)`, and that won't work.

For your current code to work right, it needs to be `dispatch(fetchDefaultConfig())`.  In other words, call the thunk action creator, and pass the returned thunk function to `dispatch`.

Personally, I would write `fetchData` as a thunk itself, and use the "object shorthand" for passing action creators to a connected component, rather than doing it in a `mapDispatch` function:

```
function fetchData() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchDefaultConfig());
        dispatch(fetchLatestSchedule());
    }
}

const mapDispatch = {fetchData};    

const MissionClockApp = connect(null, mapDispatch)(ConnectedMissionClockApp);
```

Comment: Thank you sir!  That did the trick, and your explanation was awesome.  I'm a long term Java developer who hasn't done JavaScript since about 2003, so learning all the new syntax and concepts is taking a bit for my old brain.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: Sure, glad that helped! And yes, if you haven't done JS since 2003, it's a _completely_ different language and ecosystem.  You may be interested in my lists of resources for [getting started with React](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/blogged-answers-learn-react/) and [getting started with Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/blogged-answers-learn-redux/), as well as my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).